# Returning char array fails without printf()

Tags: c, return

I have a program which takes a user input, sends that user input as an argument to a function which makes a calculation, then returns the char array to the main() function to be output there.

The `return (char *)&buf;` works fine when a `printf()` statement is run.
However, when there is no `printf()`, the return does not seem to work, as the `main()` function cannot output the returned value.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

using namespace std;

char* hash_function(char* input_string)
{
    int i = 0;
    unsigned char temp[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH]; //where we will store the SHA digest. length = 20
    char buf[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH*2];

    memset(temp, 0x0, SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH);  //array of size 20 to store SHA1 digest
    memset(buf, 0x0, SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH*2); //array of size 2*20 to store hex result?

    SHA1((unsigned char *)input_string, strlen(input_string), temp);

    for(i=0; i<SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++){
        sprintf((char*)&(buf[i*2]), "%02x", temp[i]);
        //element in temp[i] formatted with %02x and stored in buf[i*2]
    }

    //printf("In FUNCTION: %s\n", buf); //*************************************
    return (char *)&buf;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s <string>\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    char *hash = hash_function(argv[1]);

    printf("Plaintext:\t%s\nSHA-1:\t\t%s\n\n", argv[1], hash);

    //FILE *file = fopen("temp_file.txt", "a+"); //open file to write to
    //fprintf(file, "Plaintext: %s\nSHA-1: %s\n\n", argv[1], buf);

    return 0;
}
```

The line which I've marked with asterisks is the `print()` line i'm referring to.

In order to compile, use `g++ [file_name] -lcrypto -o [output]`
You may have to download the **openssl/sha.h** package.

Comment: `using namespace std;` is not C.

Comment: `buf` becomes invalid outside the function.

Comment: Please do not expect commenters to "download the openssl/sha.h package."

Comment: You can add `static` specifier to buf, the value will stay until the next call.

Comment: @theoden Not a good suggestion in general. Leads to all sorts of problems such as invalid data for earlier calls when the function is called multiple times. It's not necessary and can be solved in much better ways (e.g. return dynamic memory and caller passes in buffer).

Comment: @kaylum, yes, `static` is like singleton, and does not return anything that needs to be used twice. No need for remembering to free it though or to pass a pointer as an argument.

Comment: static = auto-unthreadsafeness ;(

Comment: the reason printf makes it work is because you entered the world of Undefined Behavior. UB means that anything can happen, including appearing to work sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

you are returning a pointer to a buffer allocated on the stack.  Once hash_buffer returns, the memory allocated to buf goes away. You need to allocate a buf on the heap with malloc.  So, change your function:

```
char* hash_function(char* input_string)
{
    int i = 0;
    unsigned char temp[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH]; //where we will store the SHA digest. length = 20
    char *buf = NULL;
    buf = malloc(SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH*2);
    if (buf == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    memset(temp, 0x0, SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH);  //array of size 20 to store SHA1 digest
    memset(buf, 0x0, SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH*2); //array of size 2*20 to store hex result?

    SHA1((unsigned char *)input_string, strlen(input_string), temp);

    for(i=0; i<SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++){
        sprintf((char*)&(buf[i*2]), "%02x", temp[i]);
        //element in temp[i] formatted with %02x and stored in buf[i*2]
    }
    return buf;
}
```

Comment: I read another thread which suggested this, but the poster was told that it's bad practice as its unclear who should be allowed to free that memory, the one who reserves or a different one? I'll go with it, I was just hoping to find a more "proper" way to go about fixing it.

Comment: It is acceptable practice to allocate memory in the function, and expect the calling routine to free it.

Comment: For improved robustness you can replace the memset calls by initializing `temp`, and using `calloc` for `buf`

Comment: The `(char *)` cast is redundant, and your loop writes past the end of the buffer by 1 byte

Comment: What @M.M says is true.  I just updated the OP's code to use `malloc`.